# UK Citizen (with USA permanent residency) Moving back to the UK Temporarily for 1 year. Can my wife work?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I have been living in the USA for 10 years and I am a Permanent resident via my wife who is a USA citizen and have a child together who was born the USA.

My wife would like to work in the UK but I am not sure if the spousal visa is right for her since we don't live in the UK or have any UK income to prove. We plan on staying with my parents while we are in the UK.

What are my options for smooth sailing?

Comment: "Smooth Sailing" in terms of application or ability to work?

Comment: ability to work

Comment: You should take care that your own American LRP status isn't lost while you're in the U.K..

Comment: From what I see, the income requirements are expressed in pounds, but there's no mention that it must be from a UK source.  The equivalent in USD should suffice.  But if you will be working for a different employer, or if the same employer will be paying you as a UK employee, you'll probably want to show a contract or other evidence of that income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to multiple sites [Visa Logic](http://www.visalogic.net/uk/uk-spouse-visa/4/103)

> **Can I work on a spouse visa?**
>
> Yes, you are eligible to work or study in the UK once the visa has been granted.

[1st Contact Visa](http://www.1stcontactvisas.com/united-kingdom/spousal-partner-visa.aspx):

> The visa, which is initially issued for a 2.5 year probationary period, allows you to work without restriction and to exit and re-enter the UK multiple times.
> Read more: http://www.1stcontactvisas.com/united-kingdom/spousal-partner-visa.aspx#ixzz3bpPSSRwa

[UK Permits](http://www.ukpermits.com/visa-types/family):

> If your application is successful under this category, you will be granted permission to live and work in the UK for a period of 30 months.

The answer is **YES**.

So if you apply and her visa is granted there should be no issue.